# section css height 100% dentro de body 100vh

Tags: html, css

tengo el siguiente codigo

```
<body>
    <section></section>
    <section></section>
</body>
```

con el siguiente css

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    padding: 10px;
     background-color: #cfcfcf;
}

section {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

section:nth-child(even) {
    position: relative;
    background: #0f0f0f;
}

</style>
```

el problema es que al darle height: 100%; y width: 100%; deberia ocupar el 100% de su contenedor pero me genera barras de scroll vertical y horizontal y me rompe el diseño. alguien sabe como solucionar este problema?[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Deben quedar un section dentro de otro section?

Comment: ¿Podrías explicar mejor el resultado visual que deseas obtener?

Comment: Quiero que el section ocupe el 100% de la pantalla disponible y tener varios section hacia abajo que cada uno ocupe el 100% que el body tenga un padding de 10px o los section tengan un marginal de 10px al body, las 2 opciones sirven

Answer (score 0):

Debes agregar overflow:hidden en tu estilo para eliminar las scroll bars. Puedes incluso utilizar overflow-x y overflow-y para solo afectar la horizontal o la vertical respectivamente.

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    padding: 10px;
     background-color: #cfcfcf;
     overflow:hidden;/*Esta línea*/
}

section {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

section:nth-child(even) {
    position: relative;
    background: #0f0f0f;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
 <section></section>
 <section></section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Si aplico el overflow: hidden no me dará problemas al centro objetos en los section?

Answer (score 0):

- No hace falta un `position` relative en el `section` par puesto que eso lo sacaría de su flujo o acomodo regular
- Al body le quitamos el `margin` que tiene y le asignamos un padding para sus elementos internos de 10px
- A cada uno de los `section` le damos un alto de 97vh para que solo ocupe el espacio visible disponible en la pantalla (mediante la medida de `vh` para el alto del viewport)
- Ele fecto del `border` con un 1px es solo para identificar visualmente donde inician y donde terminan cada uno de los `section`
- No uses el selector `*` por que es universal y eso resetea todos los estilos de cada etiqueta de tu marcación HTML, en todo caso mejor escribe a las etiquetas que has de modificar y solo aplica el estilo a ellas; ya que por ejemplo si incluyes `inputs` estos también se verán afectados por ese selector

**Código**

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>Ejemplo</title>
      <style>
        body {
          background-color: tomato;
          margin: 0;
          padding: 10px;
        } 
        section {
          background-color: rgba(134, 145, 167, 0.6);
          border: 1px solid;
          min-height: 97vh;
        }
        section:nth-child(2) {
          background-color: rgba(102, 198, 167, 0.6);
        }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <section>1</section>
    <section>2</section>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Las barras laterales de scroll son obligatorias cuando el ancho/largo excede del máximo de la pantalla. Creo entender que buscas poder cambiar de fondo gris a negro mostrando uno u otro fondo completo, sin transiciones ni barras laterales. 
Si es tu caso, te recomiendo la paginación: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_pagination.asp

Bloqueas el body con overflow:hidden, y mediante paginación enlazas botones para mostrar un fondo u otro.

```css
 * {
     box-sizing: border-box;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
 }

 body {
     width: 100vw;
     height: 100vh;
     padding: 10px;
     background-color: #cfcfcf;
     overflow: hidden;
 }

 section {
     height: 100vh;
     width: 100vw;
     margin: 0;
 }

 section:nth-child(even) {
     position: relative;
     background: #0f0f0f;
 }

 .pagination{
  text-align: center;
 }
```

```html
<html>

  <body>
      <section id="primera">
      <div class="pagination">
        <a href="#primera">1</a>
        <a href="#segunda">2</a>
      </div>

      </section>
      <section id="segunda">
      <div class="pagination">
        <a href="#primera">1</a>
        <a href="#segunda">2</a>
      </div>

      </section>
  </body>
</html>
```